# Textmate Snippet Regex to CamelCase a String

Tags: regex, textmate, code-snippets, camelcasing

I need to create a TextMate snippet that will mirror an input and make it camel cased.

The base snippet looks like this:

```
<a href="#${1}" data-toggle="tab">${1:Tab 1}</a>

Example input: Some text here
Example output: someTextHere
```

I tried doing the following as the mirror replacement, but the regex only captures the first match:

```
${1/\A(\w+)\s?/(?1:\U$1)/ig}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the "Source" bundle in Textmate? It has a "Toggle camelCase / snake_case / PascalCase" command; you could take inspiration from the regex in there.